# Redirect users with smartphones and tablets to another webpage

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, tablet, smartphone

I have a WordPress site that is responsive. The problem is that my front-page messes up when a smartphone or tablet connects to it.

Is there anyway to redirect or have a completely different page that a user who uses a smartphone or tablet gets sent to? I have seen a few sites do this, but I have not figured out how after about a few hours of searching and testing.

Anyone know of a plugin, or a code way to solve my problem?

Comment: You should check this tutorial about [mobile browser detection](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/mobile-browser-detection/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least three ways:

1. use a plugin to redirect to a new URL. If you're on WordPress 3.4+, you can use a plugin like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-mobile-url-redirect/
2. Modify your theme to detect the browser difference (Similar to this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3875/how-to-detect-mobile-devices-and-present-them-a-specific-theme). I wouldn't recommend trying this unless you authored the theme yourself.
3. Use a new theme that automatically detects mobile devices. Most newer responsive themes out there that do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You should have two separate themes where the rules applicable to the same ids and classes would be different, if possible. If not, you need to create two separate versions, one for smaller screens and one for bigger screens.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to redirect for mobile because it will affect your Website SEO So simple Use this plugin to show different pages for mobile and tablets
[enter link description here](https://codexlink.com/product/x-block)